# $\lim_{x \to + \infty} f(x)$ when $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: uniform-continuity

Does the $\lim_{x \to + \infty}$ f(x) of an uniformly continuous function exist? How to show it?
Applying the definition of uniform continuity I cannot show that...

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $f(x)=x$, which is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous, you get an counterexample. If you want a counterexample, which doesn't converges to $\infty$, just take $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, the Lipschitz can be proved using Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sin$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, and so is the function $x\mapsto 0$. What do you conclude?

Comment: Well, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)$ does not exist, while $\lim_{x\to\infty} 0 = 0$. Thus you cannot conclude existence of this limit with only the uniform continuity.